# Chat pings from wrong room

Tags: bug, chat

A small bug I may have found: I have 2 chats pinned to my tabs (Chrome), but when I'm pinged in chat #1, the noise symbol flashes from the wrong chat tab and causes me to click the wrong tab.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Things were so much easier when Chrome didn't display the origin of noises ;p

Basically, we do some really really sneaky things in chat. To reduce impact on the server, we let your tabs talk *to eachother* - they will negotiate, and one (usually the oldest) will be in charge of getting updates from the server (whether by http-polling or by web-sockets). When it has new data, the controlling tab distributes the updates to everyone.

> So; how does this impact sound?

We don't want you to be deafened by a cacophony of conflicting sounds; even if you have multiple pings in mutliple rooms, we only make a single audible sound. And historically, the most obvious way to do that was: only have the controlling tab make noises! Simple.

To get chat noises notifying on the right tab, we will need to:

- check if there are sound-worthy events in multiple rooms; if there are, probably best to just do it from the controlling tab
- if there are only sound-worthy events in a single room, delegate it to the target room

But... that still isn't enough, because the "target room" can be open *in multiple tabs* - so it would have to delegate a *specific* tab (and: I'm not even sure it knows who is listening when it broadcasts).

I'll see what I can do, but no promises!

Comment: No worries, though I will admit I did picture two browser tabs signing negotiation papers by the way you worded it :P Thank you for your time!

Comment: @SterlingArcher no paperwork; just the exchange of blood oaths

Comment: Yikes! I guess I'll go fetch the lamb :(